# How can I find which words people use to find my products?

Tags: seo

I'm creating some products, say related to kitchen stuff. I don't know what words or phrases people use to search for these products.

Is there a way to find out the searched terms related to specific industry or product, and the related words?

Answer (score 2):

Use Adwords Keyword tool. GA isn't going to give you the information you are looking for. Check the link below. Adwords, SEMRush and keywordtool.io are going to be your best bets.
http://backlinko.com/google-keyword-planner